# i want to delete the duplicate characters in the string this program is doing it right but it is not shrinking the size

Tags: c++

I want to delete the duplicate characters of the string. This program is doing it right but it's not shrinking the size

```
string key;
int index = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i< key.length(); i++) {
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j<i; j++) {
      if (key[i] == key[j])
      break;
    }
    if (j==i)
      key[index++] = key[i];
}
    cout<<key.shrink_to_fit();
```

Comment: count how many you deleted and do shrink the size?!?

Comment: Have a look at `std::string::erase`.

Comment: You can't shrink to fit, since the old characters are still there, they haven't gone anywhere. Instead, you can `key.resize(index);` given that `index` already counts the number of characters.

Comment: And how do you know it didn't shrinked ? You later check the size of it ?

Comment: One more thing, does it matter if your algorithm reorders the remaining characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to confuse capacity with the actual size. [std::string::shrink_to_fit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/shrink_to_fit) does decrease the capacity but does **not** change the size (how would it know what size you want?).

You need to decrease the size by calling [`std::string::resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize). Given that `index` is the number of characters you want to keep you'd call

```
key.resize(index);
```